# Dynamic Div Content with just clicking one link/button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help here please.

I want to show dynamic content to a div. I already have the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
  function ReplaceContentInContainer(id,content) {
  var container = document.getElementById(id);
  container.innerHTML = content;
}
//--></script>

<div id="example1div" style="padding:10px; text-align:left;">
    <p>Content 1</p>
</div>

<p align="center"><a href="javascript:ReplaceContentInContainer('example1div','<p>Content 2</p>')">View another</a></p>
```

What it does is, when click the "View another" it replace the 'Content 1' to 'Content 2' but what I want here is that, when 'Content 2' is already shown, I want to click the "View another" link again and replace the div content again with the new content like 'Content 3'.

Anyone please help me solve this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: how do you define the contents to be shown? is there an array?

Comment: i don't know how to do that...when you run my code above, when click 'View another' text it will replace the 'Content 1' to 'Content 2'..I want to replace again the 'Content 2' with 'Content 3' when click 'View another' again..please help

Answer (score 1):

Updated after OP's comment

**HTML**

include jQuery library file

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Use Plugin https://github.com/fkling/jQuery-Function-Toggle-Plugin --> It accepts an arbitrary number of functions and can be used for any event.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8GmtV/)

You want something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*
 * jQuery Function Toggle Pluing
 * Copyright 2011, Felix Kling
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
 */

(function ($) {
    $.fn.funcToggle = function (type, data) {
        var dname = "jqp_eventtoggle_" + type + (new Date()).getTime(),
            funcs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2),
            numFuncs = funcs.length,
            empty = function () {},
            false_handler = function () {
                return false;
            };

        if (typeof type === "object") {
            for (var key in type) {
                $.fn.funcToggle.apply(this, [key].concat(type[key]));
            }
            return this;
        }
        if ($.isFunction(data) || data === false) {
            funcs = [data].concat(funcs);
            numFuncs += 1;
            data = undefined;
        }

        funcs = $.map(funcs, function (func) {
            if (func === false) {
                return false_handler;
            }
            if (!$.isFunction(func)) {
                return empty;
            }
            return func;
        });

        this.data(dname, 0);
        this.bind(type, data, function (event) {
            var data = $(this).data(),
                index = data[dname];
            funcs[index].call(this, event);
            data[dname] = (index + 1) % numFuncs;
        });
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));

$('#chnage_p').funcToggle('click', function () {
    $('#example1div').text('Content 1');
}, function () {
    $('#example1div').text('Content 2');
}, function () {
    $('#example1div').text('Content 3');
}, function () {
    $('#example1div').text('Content 4');
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for the demo but when i copied it to my local file..it doesn't work..what are the things that need to add in my html doc. please help..thank you.

Comment: i got it now. Thanks so much @TusharGupta

Comment: @user2778297 if you are satisfied accept the answer http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png